# Remove duplicates in a list while keeping its order (Python)

Tags: python, list

This is actually an extension of this question. The answers of that question did not keep the "order" of the list after removing duplicates. [How to remove these duplicates in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534736/how-to-remove-these-duplicates-in-a-list-python)

```
biglist = 

[ 

    {'title':'U2 Band','link':'u2.com'}, 
    {'title':'Live Concert by U2','link':'u2.com'},
    {'title':'ABC Station','link':'abc.com'}

]
```

In this case, the 2nd element should be removed because a previous "u2.com" element already exists.  However, the order should be kept.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My answer to your other question, which you completely ignored!, shows you're wrong in claiming that

> The answers of that question did not
>   keep the "order"

- my answer **did** keep order, and it clearly **said** it did.  Here it is again, with added emphasis to see if you can just keep ignoring it...:

Probably the fastest approach, for a really big list, **if you want to preserve the exact order of the items that remain**, is the following...:

```
biglist = [ 
    {'title':'U2 Band','link':'u2.com'}, 
    {'title':'ABC Station','link':'abc.com'}, 
    {'title':'Live Concert by U2','link':'u2.com'} 
]

known_links = set()
newlist = []

for d in biglist:
  link = d['link']
  if link in known_links: continue
  newlist.append(d)
  known_links.add(link)

biglist[:] = newlist
```

Comment: Hey Alex, out of curiosity why do you put the [:] on the left hand side of the assignment?  I've usually seen it on the RHS.  Is it just personal preference?  Looking at it at first I wasn't even sure what it would do, haha.

Comment: @xitrium Using `[:]` on the left replaced all the items in the list, instead of the list itself. It could have an effect e.g. if you do this inside a function with a list that is passed in: if you *change* the list it's changed outside the function, if you *replace* it then the outside list is unaffected). In this particular case, there are no observable effect that I can see.

Answer (score 39):

use set(), then re-sort using the index of the original list.

```
>>> mylist = ['c','a','a','b','a','b','c']
>>> sorted(set(mylist), key=lambda x: mylist.index(x))
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind explaining how it works? (with the use of lambda etc) Thanks

Comment: Neat Python code. The downside is that it causes an extra sort, thus an unneeded O(n * log(n)) (where otherwise O(n) would be sufficient).

Comment: Worse, it calls `.index` for each distinct element, which does a linear search, so it's an unneeded O(n^2).

Answer (score 13):

Generators are great.

```
def unique( seq ):
    seen = set()
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add( item )
            yield item

biglist[:] = unique( biglist )
```

Comment: This is what I needed for my problem. I would suggest making it more generic adding `key=lambda item: item` to the method signature. Then, use `key(item)` for the set.

Answer (score 3):

This page discusses different methods and their speeds:
http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

The recommended* method:

```
def f5(seq, idfun=None):  
    # order preserving 
    if idfun is None: 
        def idfun(x): return x 
    seen = {} 
    result = [] 
    for item in seq: 
        marker = idfun(item) 
        # in old Python versions: 
        # if seen.has_key(marker) 
        # but in new ones: 
        if marker in seen: continue 
        seen[marker] = 1 
        result.append(item) 
    return result

f5(biglist,lambda x: x['link'])
```

*by that page

Answer (score 3):

This is an elegant and compact way, with list comprehension (but not as efficient as with dictionary):

```
mylist = ['aaa','aba','aaa','aea','baa','aaa','aac','aaa',]

[ v for (i,v) in enumerate(mylist) if v not in mylist[0:i] ]
```

And in the context of the answer:

```
[ v for (i,v) in enumerate(biglist) if v['link'] not in map(lambda d: d['link'], biglist[0:i]) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dups = {}
newlist = []
for x in biglist:
    if x['link'] not in dups:
      newlist.append(x)
      dups[x['link']] = None

print newlist
```

produces

```
[{'link': 'u2.com', 'title': 'U2 Band'}, {'link': 'abc.com', 'title': 'ABC Station'}]
```

Note that here I used a dictionary. This makes the test `not in dups` much more efficient than using a list.

Comment: You're wrong about checking in a dict being faster than in a set (lists are a completely different matter).

Comment: ok, fixed, thanks. I guess set is probably implemented with a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
list = ['aaa','aba','aaa','aea','baa','aaa','aac','aaa',]
uniq = []
for i in list:
               if i not in uniq:
                   uniq.append(i)

print list
print uniq
```

output will be :

```
['aaa', 'aba', 'aaa', 'aea', 'baa', 'aaa', 'aac', 'aaa']
['aaa', 'aba', 'aea', 'baa', 'aac']
```

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way to do this is:

```
def uniq(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [a[0]] + uniq([x for x in a if x != a[0]])
```

This is not the most efficient way, because:

- it searches through the whole list for every element in the list, so it's O(n^2)
- it's recursive so uses a stack depth equal to the length of the list

However, for simple uses (no more than a few hundred items, not performance critical) it is sufficient.

Comment: Can anyone come up with a way that is scalable?

Answer (score 0):

I think using a set should be pretty efficent.

```
seen_links = set()
for index in len(biglist):
    link = biglist[index]['link']
    if link in seen_links:
        del(biglist[index])
    seen_links.add(link)
```

I think this should come in at O(nlog(n))

Comment: in fact it is O(n^2) because del on a list is O(n)