# remove duplicate list elements

Tags: python

I want to remove the duplicate elements in a list only when one element is repeated many times, like this:

```
li = ['Human','Human','Human'] => li = ['Human']
```

but not when there are two or more different elements:

```
li = ['Human','Monkey','Human', 'Human']
```

Comment: Isn't that what a `set` is?  Why aren't you using a set?

Comment: @S.Lott: I did that mistake too, but read the second line.. ^^

Comment: @S. Lott. because he only wants duplicates removed if there is only one distinct value in the list. ordering might also be a concern.

Comment: This is homework.  I saw it last semester.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549509/remove-duplicates-in-a-list-while-keeping-its-order-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so-t, etc.

Comment: Where did that answer disappear to? I thought that was correct? o.O

Comment: @poke I deleted it but I guess the damage was already done. I dropped out of high school so I guess I don't mind stealing OP's education if they're giving it away for free. It would be nice if that came with a piece of paper but oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def clean(lst):
    if lst.count(lst[0]) == len(lst):
        return [lst[0]]
    else:
        return lst
```

Does that do what you want?

if so, then you can do it in place as well

```
def clean_in_place(lst):
    if lst.count(lst[0]) == len(lst):
        lst[:] = [lst[0]]
```

Comment: That works great! btw was how do you clean duplicates if the successive elements are same, like ['a','a','a','b','a','a'] to ['a','b','a']

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily with sets as below:

```
li = list(set(li))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['Human','Human','Human'] => lst = ['Human']
lst = ['Human','Monkey','Human', 'Human'] => lst = ['Human','Monkey','Human', 'Human']
```

it was do what you want?

```
if lst.count(lst[0])==len(lst):
   lst=list(set(lst))
   print lst 
else:
   print lst
```