# python get non repeating items - fastest method

Tags: python

I am searching for items that are not repeated in a list in python.
The current way I do it is,

```
python -mtimeit -s'l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*99' '[x for x in l if l.count(x) == 1]'
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 msec per loop
```

Is it possible to do it faster?

This is the output.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*99+[10,11]
>>> [x for x in l if l.count(x) == 1]
[10, 11]
```

Comment: This is something like `O(n^2)`. Using a hash set can give you `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: How would you expect l to have non-repeating items when you are repeating itself?

Comment: BartoszKP, I'll lookup what you said, but an example would help. Srinivas, that's not the point of the question. It's about speed.

Comment: @Omair.: If speed is a concern, don't implement it in Python. Write a C extension.

Comment: @Blender: Well, when it’s a matter of time complexity…

Comment: Blender, beyond me. :-) eacousineau, nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `Counter` class](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
...
[item for item, count in Counter(l).items() if count == 1]
```

My results:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from collections import Counter; l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] * 99' '[item for item, count in Counter(l).items() if count == 1]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 366 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*99' '[x for x in l if l.count(x) == 1]'
10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 msec per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! Speed increases, 457usec.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove duplicate entries, so there are some answers here:

- [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)
- [Remove duplicates in a list while keeping its order (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549550/170413)

Using `in` as opposed to `count()` should be a little quicker because the query is done once it finds the first instance.

Comment: These are different problems.

Comment: Hmm... How so? Would the `f7()` function not address that, using a `set()`?

Comment: `f([1, 2, 3, 3])` should return `[1, 2]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`, as `3` appeared more than once.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. OP wants to count the number of non-unique elements. My bad.