# Remove duplicates from Array string

Tags: python

It's really childish to ask this question but really want an optimal solution for this.
I have an array of string

```
("a1,a2", "a3,a4", "a2,a1", "a5,a3")
```

and I want to Display

```
("a1,a2", "a3,a4", "a5,a3")
```

i.e. the first string is in, its duplicates are omitted.

Note: the order of the elements must be preserved

Comment: Also this is a tuple, not an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in a list while keeping its order (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549509/remove-duplicates-in-a-list-while-keeping-its-order-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
data =  ("a1,a2","a3,a4","a2,a1","a5,a3") 
seen = set()
result = []
for i in data:
    if ",".join(sorted(i.split(","))) not in seen:
        result.append(i)
        seen.add(i) 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['a1,a2', 'a3,a4', 'a5,a3']
```

Comment: the inner list (the one inside `set`) is unnecessary

Comment: I forgot to add about the "order" in the question. Actually order is required. Thank you for the answer. will try the answer.

Comment: @SharathNayak. Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

your data is in a variable called "data".

```
new_data = []
for example in data:
    example2 = str(example.split(",")[1] + "," + example.split(",")[0])
    if example in new_data or example2 in new_data:
        continue 
    else:
        new_data.append(example) 
print(new_data)
```

If you want to store them in your original list, run this script.

```
data.clear()
data = new_data.copy()
```